# DataJoins in Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to implement one use case as given in Book Hadoop In Action, but I am not being to compile the code. I am new to Java so, not being able to understand the exact reasons behind the errors.

Interesting thing is, another piece of coding using same classes and methods are compiled successfully.

```
hadoop@hadoopnode1:~/hadoop-0.20.2/playground/src$ javac -classpath /home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/hadoop-0.20.2-core.jar:/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.2/contrib/datajoin/hadoop-0.20.2-datajoin.jar -d ../classes DataJoin2.java 
DataJoin2.java:49: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor TaggedWritable(org.apache.hadoop.io.Text)
location: class DataJoin2.TaggedWritable
            TaggedWritable retv = new TaggedWritable((Text) value);
                                  ^
DataJoin2.java:69: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor TaggedWritable(org.apache.hadoop.io.Text)
location: class DataJoin2.TaggedWritable
            TaggedWritable retv = new TaggedWritable(new Text(joinedStr));
                                  ^
DataJoin2.java:113: setMapperClass(java.lang.Class<? extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper>) in org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job cannot be applied to (java.lang.Class<DataJoin2.MapClass>)
        job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
           ^
DataJoin2.java:114: setReducerClass(java.lang.Class<? extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer>) in org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job cannot be applied to (java.lang.Class<DataJoin2.Reduce>)
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
           ^
4 errors
```

----------------code----------------------

```
import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;


import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.KeyValueTextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

// DataJoin Classes
import org.apache.hadoop.contrib.utils.join.DataJoinMapperBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.contrib.utils.join.TaggedMapOutput;
import org.apache.hadoop.contrib.utils.join.DataJoinReducerBase;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;


public class DataJoin2
{
    public static class MapClass extends DataJoinMapperBase
    {
        protected Text generateInputTag(String inputFile)
        {
            String datasource = inputFile.split("-")[0];
            return new Text(datasource);            
        }

        protected Text generateGroupKey(TaggedMapOutput aRecord)
        {
            String line = ((Text) aRecord.getData()).toString();
            String[] tokens = line.split(",");
            String groupKey = tokens[0];
            return new Text(groupKey);
        }

        protected TaggedMapOutput generateTaggedMapOutput(Object value)
        {
            TaggedWritable retv = new TaggedWritable((Text) value);
            retv.setTag(this.inputTag);
            return retv;
        }
    } // End of class MapClass

    public static class Reduce extends DataJoinReducerBase
    {
        protected TaggedMapOutput combine(Object[] tags, Object[] values)
        {
            if (tags.length < 2) return null;
            String joinedStr = "";
            for (int i=0;i<values.length;i++)
            {
                if (i>0) joinedStr += ",";
                TaggedWritable tw = (TaggedWritable) values[i];
                String line = ((Text) tw.getData()).toString();
                String[] tokens = line.split(",",2);
                joinedStr += tokens[1];
            }
            TaggedWritable retv = new TaggedWritable(new Text(joinedStr));
            retv.setTag((Text) tags[0]);
            return retv;
        }
    } // End of class Reduce

    public static class TaggedWritable extends TaggedMapOutput 
    {
        private Writable data;

        public TaggedWritable()
        {
            this.tag = new Text("");
            this.data = data;
        }

        public Writable getData()
        {
            return data;
        }

        public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException
        {
            this.tag.write(out);
            this.data.write(out);
        }

        public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException
        {
            this.tag.readFields(in);
            this.data.readFields(in);
        }       
    } // End of class TaggedWritable

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
          System.err.println("Usage: DataJoin2 <in> <out>");
          System.exit(2);
        }
        Job job = new Job(conf, "DataJoin");
        job.setJarByClass(DataJoin2.class);     
        job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(TaggedWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing ambiguous about the error message.  It is telling you that you did not provide a constructor for `TaggedWritable` which takes an argument of type `Text`. You only show a no-arg constructor in the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks for pointing....This is what happens when someone from Oracle background tries hand with Java

Answer (score 1):

For your *first two* error messages, the compiler errors are *clearly* telling you that you don't have a constructor for `TaggedWritable` that accepts an argument of type `Text`. It appears to me that you are making `TaggedWritable` serve as a wrapper for `Writable` to add a tag, so may I suggest adding constructor with:

```
public TaggedWritable(Writable data) {
    this.tag = new Text("");
    this.data = data;
}
```

In fact, as you've written it, this line

```
this.data = data;
```

just reassigns `data` to itself, so I'm pretty sure you intended to have a constructor argument named `data`. See my reasoning above for why I think you should make it `Writable` instead of `Text`. Since `Text` implements `Writable`, this *will* resolve your first two error messages.

However, you will need to *keep* a default no-arg constructor. This is because Hadoop will use reflection to instantiate an instance `Writable` values as it serializes them across the network between the map reduce phases. I think you have a tiny bit of a mess here for the default no-arg constructor:

```
public TaggedWritable() {
    this.tag = new Text("");
}
```

The reason that I see this as a mess is because if you don't assign to `TaggedWritable.data` a  valid instance of whatever your wrapped `Writable` values are, you will get a `NullPointerException` when `this.data.readFields(in)` is invoked in `TaggedWritable.readFields(DataInput)`. Since it's a general wrapper, you should probably make `TaggedWritable` a generic type and then use reflection to assign to `TaggedWritable.data` in the default no-arg constructor.

For your *last two* compiler errors, to use `hadoop-datajoin` I note that you need to be using the *old API* classes. Thus, all of these

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
```

should be replaced by their old API equivalents. So `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf` instead of `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job`, etc. That will handle your last two error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I have hadoop-2,7,1, for me worked to add dependency from MAven, in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-datajoin</artifactId>
<version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the Url for hadoop-datajoin : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-datajoin